# insert IF into Foreach with Variable $html .=

Tags: php

I'm breaking my head with this and can not get it to work, I hope someone can help me put the PHP code within the variable `$html` specifically where the symbols `#########################`

**Code PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {$ciudad_id = $_POST['ciudad']; if($ciudad_id == $v1->id) echo 'selected="selected"';}
```

**Insert here (###...):**

```
<?php
$html = '<option value="">Selecciona ciudad</option>';

foreach ($Ciudades as $v1) { 
 $html .= '<option value="'.$v1->id.'" ######################### >'.$v1->ciudad.'</option>';
} 

echo $html;
?>
```

Thank you very much for your help, I'm desperate...

Comment: you should be getting an error about it, like unexpected T_IF. You need to break them up. Better yet; use a ternary operator.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {$ciudad_id = $_POST['ciudad']; if($ciudad_id == $v1->id){$html .= '<option selected="selected" value="'.$v1->id.'">'.$v1->ciudad.'</option>';}}$html .= '<option value="'.$v1->id.'">'.$v1->ciudad.'</option>';`

Comment: you can use code of this link:- https://eval.in/656574

Comment: @Anant Thank you very much for your help, this worked correctly, greetings!

Comment: @GePraxa  welcome. cheers :):)